# How do I convert this string to milliseconds?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, time, duration, milliseconds

I’m using Rails 4.2.7.  I want to calculate the number of milliseconds given a duration, which could include hours, minutes, and seconds.  So I wrote these two functions:

```
def convert_to_hrs(string)
  if !string.nil?
    string.strip!
    case string.count(':')
    when 0
      '00:00:' + string.rjust(2, '0')
    when 1
      '00:' + string
    else
      string
    end
  else
    "00:00:00"
  end
end

def duration_in_milliseconds(input)
  input = convert_to_hrs(input)
  if input.match(/\d+:\d\d:\d\d\.?\d*/)
    h, m, s = input.split(':').map(&:to_i)
    (h.hours + m.minutes + s.seconds) * 1000
  else
    0
  end
end
```

Unfortunately, when I call `duration_in_milliseconds(input)` with a number like `8:49`, the result is `zero`.  The result should be interpreted as `8 minutes and 49 seconds`, which in milliseconds would be `529000`.  How do I adjust the above to account for this?

Comment: This means your conditional has failed and implies your regex is incorrect. Can you give examples of input strings?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'll just leave this one here:

```
def convert_to_ms(string)
  string.split(':').map(&:to_i).inject(0) { |a, b| a * 60 + b } * 1000
end

convert_to_ms('8:49')
#=> 529000
```

Comment: This one is awesome!

Answer (score 0):

Just another implementation.. Cause it's fun :)

```
def duration_in_milliseconds(string)
  string.split(':')
  .map(&:to_i)
  .reverse
  .zip([1,60,3600])
  .map{ |segment, multiplier| segment*multiplier }
  .inject(:+) * 1000
end
```